# Permutation of vertices of a square $(D_{4})$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, permutations

$D_{4}$, the dihedral group of order 8 is a square.

Suppose the vertices are labelled in an anti-clockwise fashion, starting with 1 at the bottom right corner. Each rotation is $\frac{2\pi}{4}$=90

Let $\rho$ be the rotation function in anti-clockwise motion and $\phi$ be the reflection about the horizontal axis.

Then,

$\rho=\begin{bmatrix}
1 &2  &3  &4 \\ 
2 &3  &4  &1 
\end{bmatrix}$

and 
$\phi=\begin{bmatrix}
1 &2  &3  &4 \\ 
2 &1  &4  &3 
\end{bmatrix}$

I'll like to know how $D_{4}$ is a subgroup of $S_{4}$. Can someone help me?

Comment: You can see that any matrix-like representation of the elements of $\;D_4\;$ represents a bijection $\;\{1,2,3,4\}\to\{1,2,3,4\}\;$ .

Comment: $\varphi$ is wrong since your $\varphi=\rho^2$. Here $\varphi=(12)$.

Comment: @Surb how is $\varphi=\rho^2$ ?